# Mushroom soup prep in advance

Tags: storage-lifetime

Want to make cream of mushroom soup for Boxing Day (26th Dec). How long can I prepare in advance? Planning to cook the mushrooms in white wine and garlic. Boil than cool and blend so I can just add the cream before serving.  Will it be OK to cook  now (23rd) ?

Answer (score 1):

Minimum 3 days, technically safe for 5 and personally I'd be happy for 7. This applies to all soup pretty much, not just mushroom.

So to answer your question, yes you are more than safe doing it today. I did mine yesterday.